# 404 error installing virtualbox on debian testing

Tags: debian, virtualbox, apt

When attempting to install Virtualbox on Debian Testing, I'm getting a 404 error from the repository after I've added it.

Contents of `apt update`:

```
Hit:1 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian testing InRelease
Ign:2 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian testing InRelease
Err:3 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian testing Release
404  Not Found [IP: 23.218.90.109 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian testing Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Contents of `/etc/apt/sources/list`:

```
# 

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux testing _Buster_ - Official Snapshot amd64    xfce-CD Binary-1 20190107-04:42]/ buster main

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux testing _Buster_ - Official Snapshot amd64 xfce-CD Binary-1 20190107-04:42]/ buster main

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing main

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian testing contrib
# deb-src http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian testing contrib
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to using Debian Testing instead of Stable/Stretch, I had to install VirtualBox like it's installed for Ubuntu 18.0.4. Instructions for this I found here: https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/install-virtualbox-4-5-ubuntu-16-04.html

Answer (score 2):

You need the release file from the virtual box repository (as i believe)
try these :

```
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

Comment: hope i helped :D !!

Comment: When i try to do this I get `gpg: can't open 'oracle_vbox_2016.asc': No such file or directory`

Comment: hmmmmmmmmmm ok 
I would try 2 things :
1) https://wiki.debian.org/VirtualBox || See if it helps  depending on witch debian you have
2)gedit  /etc/apt/sources.list
 >and add to deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian stretch contrib (probablyt tihs will be the link)
"non-free" withouth the " "

Comment: sorry for the bad syntax here still new to stackoverflow ;-;

Comment: Can't switch it to install stretch, since several packages its dependent on are updated on testing.

Comment: I have discovered Virtualbox doesn't have a version for Debian testing, so you apparently have to install it like it's installed on Ubuntu v18.0.4

Comment: what do you mean when you say testing because i have virtualbox on my debian distro with the link that i attached above :/

Answer (score 1):

You can also install Virtualbox on debian Buster from debian repository.

Edit your `sources.list`

```
apt edit-sources
```

with the following lines (`contrib` component added) :

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ buster main contrib
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ buster main contrib

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib 
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib
```

Then :

```
apt update
apt install virtualbox
```